# Drawing random float from probability distribution with dynamic mean in python

Tags: python, random, probability, distribution

I am looking for a way to draw a random float from a probability distribution of which the mean or loc has the value of a node in a model. On top of this, the numbers drawn should not exceed the range of [-1.0, 1.0] and should not have more than 1 decimal.

[Kinda like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFHVa.png)

So if the value of the node is lets say 0.8, loc should be 0.8, but values outside 1 can't be drawn. I'm really new to programming so if anyone can give me any tips on whether this is possible to begin with it would be much appreciated. With normal([loc, scale, size] its not possible I think. Thanks in advance

---

Thanks so much for your answer. My bad, I meant 2 decimals! Which makes the solution different to your suggestion I guess because then the the amount of numbers increases quite a lot and maybe the approach is unfeasable?

Right now I have this:

def randomnumber(loc, scale): 
    return  np.random.normal(loc, scale, size=None)

```
                elif node == 'is_po': 
                      for neig in graph.predecessors(node):
                        neig_w = graph.edges[neig, node]['weight']
                        neig_s = graph.node[neig]['status'][t - delta_t]

                        loc = neig_s
                        scale = 1

                        c = randomnumber(loc, scale)
                        graph.node[node]['status'][t] = c * delta_t
```

Which seems to give me a random number back drawn around the value of neig_s, but I don't know if it is possible to make sure that the random numbers drawn dont come from above 1 or below -1.

Comment: So you want them still normally distributed like in your plot?

Comment: If one of the answers provided meets your needs, you should check it off as the answer.  If not, you should edit your question to clarify what issues remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want a normally distributed number with scale=1. A simple solution is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
def func(loc):
    max_iter = 1000
    x = np.random.normal(loc)
    c = 0
    while c < max_iter:
        if x > -1 and x < 1:
            return x
        c += 1
        x = np.random.normal(loc)
    print('max iter exceeded')
```

Be aware that if you give high or low value for the loc parameter then the while loop will run forever therefore I set a limit 'max_iter'.

If you want a more advanced solution then you have define a truncated normal distribution (you can do this in scipy).

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want one decimal place for your results, what you're describing isn't a continuous distribution on the range [-1,1] but rather a discrete distribution scaled to that range. There are 21 allowable values (-1.0, -0.9, -0.8,..., 0.8, 0.9, 1.0), so one approach is to use a discrete distribution which yields results on the range [0,...,20]. You would then scale and translate your `target` mean to its corresponding `scaled_target` value between 0 and 20, generate a value from some distribution with that mean, and scale the result back to the range [-1,...,1].

Forward scaling is accomplished via the relationship `scaled_target = 20 * (target + 1) / 2`. For instance, `target = 0.8` would yield `scaled_target = 18`, so you would generate values between 0 and 20 with a mean of 18. You then scale back into the range [-1,...,1] by subtracting 10 from the outcome and dividing by 10.

One easy-to-use distribution would be the binomial with `n = 20` to yield the desired range.  Since the mean of a binomial is `n * p` and you want a mean of 18, you would use `p = 0.9`, which can be derived directly as `(target_mean + 1.0) / 2.0` — no need to multiply by 20 and then divide by 20.

The forward and reverse scaling take only a couple of lines of code, and you can use `numpy` (or `scipy` if you prefer) to generate the binomial distribution:

```
import numpy

def generate_value(target_mean):
    scaled_target = (target_mean + 1.0) / 2.0
    return (numpy.random.binomial(n = 20, p = scaled_target) - 10.0) / 10.0
```

Sample output:

```
print([generate_value(target_mean = 0.8) for _ in range(10)])  # => [0.8, 0.9, 0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 0.8]
print([generate_value(target_mean = 0.0) for _ in range(10)])  # => [-0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, -0.3, -0.4, -0.2, -0.1, -0.2, 0.3]
```

If you want a broader range of outcomes, you'll need to pick a different discrete distribution, but the approach generalizes pretty straightforwardly.

---

**ADDENDUM**

Revising this to two decimal places does not change the structure of the approach, only the scaling:

```
def generate_value(target_mean):
    scaled_target = (target_mean + 1.0) / 2.0
    return (numpy.random.binomial(n = 200, p = scaled_target) - 100.0) / 100.0
```

If the values generated with a simple binomial are too clustered for you, you can replace it with a [beta-binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) by dynamically generating the binomial's `p` using a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with α scaled to yield outcomes with an expected value of `scaled_target` and β scaled to yield an appropriate dispersion of the outcomes:

```
import numpy

BETA_SHAPE = 2.0    # larger values will yield more clustered outcomes

def generate_value(target_mean):
    scaled_target = (target_mean + 1.0) / 2.0
    alpha = BETA_SHAPE * scaled_target / (1.0 - scaled_target)
    beta_p = numpy.random.beta(a = alpha, b = BETA_SHAPE)
    return (numpy.random.binomial(n = 200, p = beta_p) - 100.0) / 100.0
```

Sample output:

```
lst = [generate_value(target_mean = 0.7) for _ in range(10000)]
print(numpy.mean(lst))    # => 0.695812
print(min(lst))           # => -0.37
print(max(lst))           # => 1.0
```

The specific choice of distribution is up to you, but the approach is a general one.  This also gives the precise mean you're interested in, while answers based on truncating or acceptance/rejection will shift the mean.

Comment: Thanks so much for your elaborate answer. I made a mistake by saying 1 decimal, as I want two (0.54, -0.74). I assume this approach is not feasable anymore then because the amount of numbers increases drammatically. 
Nonetheless, I'll try this method as well.